# Is there an algorithm that probably solves the Halting problem?

Tags: computer-science, computability

Such an algorithm takes as input any program and returns a probability that it halts.

In the limit of many programs, it must answer on average in the correct proportion. But im interested in other interesting conditions for a succesfull algorithm

Comment: related: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/can-a-probabilistic-turing-machine-solve-the-halting-problem

Comment: Maybe I don't know what you mean by "it must answer on average in the correct proportion", but this probably depends on the coding of machines. For example, you could just force that for every number not of the form $2^n$, the machine with that code halts. Then I guess there's an algorithm that works usually. See what I mean?

Comment: Any algorithm will **certainly not** completely solve the Halting problem (no probability other then $0$ there). The probability that a given program on a given input halts is either $0$ or $1$, and finding that probability is the same as deciding whether the combination will halt or not. Also it seems rather pointless to get the correct proportion of answers if they are not attributed to the correct inputs: it would be like claiming on a multiple-choice test that although you got most of the answers wrong, you did get the correct distribution of a/b/c/d. I can see no reasonable question here.

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen, I think OP uses the term 'proportion' in way intended to imply that the proportion of incorrect responses diminishes to zero as the program is applied to all integers under an increasing bound. So probability is referring to the probability that, under some set bound, a given response is correct; and this probability limits to 1.

Comment: @jack: If OP means that, I think the question should be edited so as to make the clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are several significant ambiguities in your question. The way the machines are encoded matters for this, as does the model of computation. Also, do you mean that the machine always halts, or that it halts for zero input? I will make reasonable assumptions to resolve these ambiguities, if that does not do it for you you will need to clarify your question.

Suppose the computational model is the single one way infinite tape binary alphabet Turing Machine model. Suppose the initial input is zero; a machine running on nonzero input is equivalent to some easily identified machine with more states running on zero input, so this is a reasonable assumption. Finally, list the machines such that $k<m$ implies machine $k$ has no more states than machine $m$; this is not overly restrictive, as one would expect any reasonable encoding to be close enough to this for the following to work.

It has recently been proven that a polynomial time program can decide all but a diminishing proportion of TM's, see http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504351. Then you could just run this program and guess on machines it can't decide (or say they all halt or all don't, or whatever). Since the possible mistakes are a diminishing proportion of inputs, this is the algorithm you are looking for.

The result this answer relies on applies with additional tapes and characters in the alphabet. I do not think it is yet known to apply in the case of the two way infinite tape. However, it seems to me that this is likely the case. The paper I cited actually states this as an open question.

Comment: Averaging over all possible Turing machines (with respect to some measure) is like averaging over all programs written by a company of monkeys (no offence to the simian species intended). It is not really surprising that the halting problem is easy for the vast majority of them.

Comment: Well, some unsurprising results are extremely difficult to prove (e.g., Fermat's Last Theorem), so it can be of interest to know if an expected result is actually proven. Also, $P\neq NP$ seems quite unsurprising, but the most interesting outcome would be if its wrong. Never trust an assumption until is it proven, and sometimes you will gain surprising insights.

Comment: In fact, this result is not even known to be the case for 2-way tapes, as far as I know, so unsurprising as it may be, it is still an open question under that interpretation.